# iPhone: Conditionally load views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, nsuserdefaults

I have a login screen set as main view, and when the user successfully logs in, I set a user default with their username and a bool saying they are logged in.

My question is, what is the best method for checking if they are logged in next time they load the app, AND show them a different view if they ARE logged in?

I have tried just checking this in my login screens viewDidLoad method, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  I am looking for a preferred method, and the RIGHT way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check it in the app delegates

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method & add the respective view in it here

```
[window loginViewController.view]; //other view if logged in
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```